# Calculating distance between 2 coordinates in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, radians

Currently I am trying to populate the distance between 2 coordinates in Access. I found a VBA function online that allows me to use ACOR and RADIANS in access. The function worked, but when I attempt to "Make Table", I keep running into an error that says "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument". Keep it mind the data contains 4,000,000+ records.

Does anyone know how to fix this VBA issue?

Below is the code

```
    Const pi = 3.14159265358979

Function ACos(ang As Double) As Double

If Abs(ang) <> 1 Then

ACos = pi / 2 - Atn(ang / Sqr(1 - ang * ang))

ElseIf ang = -1 Then

ACos = pi

End If

End Function

Function Radians(ang As Double) As Double

Radians = ang * pi / 180

End Function
```

Also below is the Make Table Code:

```
Distance: ACOS(Cos(RADIANS(90-[Latitude]))*Cos(RADIANS(90-[Dlatitude]))+Sin(RADIANS(90-[DLatitude]))*Sin(RADIANS(90-[DLatitude]))*Cos(RADIANS([Longitude]-[DLongitude])))*3858
```

Comment: Where is the "Make Table" code? If it stops in this routine, which line does it stop on?

Comment: My apologies...I included it in the post. THank you!

Comment: 1. Add the word Public in front of the word Function in your code.  2. Put this code in a declared module in VBA.  3. Do Not name your module ACos or Radians, it will hide that function from view.